# default spring data elasticsearch `CrudRepository` doesn't support routing

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring data `CrudRepository`'s `findById` method is useful and handy to use, but in spring-data-elasticsearch, we should specify not only `id` but `routing` attribute together to find a doc in index with multiple shards.

1. Does it mean `CrudRepository#findById` is useless or even misleading(if `_id` is not equal to `_routing`) in spring-data-elasticsearch?
2. Is there any way to find a doc by id and routing, without construct a search request manually, in spring-data-elasticsearch?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Routing support is available since version 4.2 (released in April 2021) and [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.routing).

It is supported on the `ElastcisearchOperations` level.

To use it in a repository you'd need to integrate it in a [custom repository fragment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: Thanks, so that still means writing the `findById`(with routing) query manually? Rather than such a method already existed?

Comment: After watching `DocumentOperations#get` and `RoutingResolver#getRouting`, I think i understand how to do it: 1. define `findById` in custom repository; 2. and fullfill it using `DocumentOperations#get` + custom `RoutingResolver` or a custom object bean to supply routing info; right?

Comment: Hey Meisch, I think you partly misunderstood my question. I know spring-data-elsticsearch supports specifying `_routing`. What I what to figure out is the question one above. Do you think `CrudRepository#findById` created by spring-data is a misleading method in spring-data-elasticsearch and should be avoided to use?

Comment: Well, if the default implementation `findById` does not what you need - in this case using a routing value - then it's not the right method to use. And yes, redefine the method in a custom repository fragment.